# how can I turn off one module of my project's log.info?

Tags: python, logging

I want set logging level of `requests` to `logging.WARN` only.

Most of time, `logging.DEBUG` works for me, but when I add `requests` to my project, `requests` log out too much.

I can simply just change the level to `WARN` globally, but then I miss many logs from others, I just want to turn off the logs of `requests` only?

Here is part of my `logging.yaml`:

```
handlers:

    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: colored
        stream: ext://sys.stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a logger for requests and use qualname to limit said logger to a certain channel:

```
loggers:
    requests:
        qualname: requests
        level: WARN
        handlers:
```